# How to find value from a slab range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter commission depend on amount means I give a amount like 300000 and get the commission for those slab where 300000 is match

| SlabStartAmount | SlabEndAmount | CommissionAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100000 | 200000 | 62.5 |
| 2000001 | 5000000 | 75 |
| 5000001 | 7500000 | 81.25 |
| 7500001 | 10000000 | 87.5 |
| 10000001 | 0 | 100 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a condition to find out the slab

```
WHERE @Amount BETWEEN SlabStartAmount AND SlabEndAmount
```

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9c8ca07731a1922e1da0393b35f1927).